# Javascript to stay on the particular div

Tags: javascript

The following is the code i am using for drag and drop functionality for the div contents..

```
<style type="text/css">
.gap
{

 border:1px solid black

}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">


function toggle_visibility(id,nana) {
   var e =document.getElementById(id);
   var label = document.getElementById(nana);

   if(e.style.display == 'none')
    {
      label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace("[+]","[-]");
      e.style.display = 'block';
      //col.innerHTML=valu;
    }
   else
   {
      label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace("[-]","[+]");
      e.style.display = 'none';

   }
}    

    function edit(id,item)
    {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       var f = document.getElementById(item);

     document.getElementById('id4').innerHTML=e.innerHTML;     
      e.innerHTML=f.innerHTML;
      window.location=window.location;

    }
    function cancel(id,item)
    {

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=document.getElementById(item).innerHTML;
    }

function submit(id,item)
    {

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=document.getElementById(item).innerHTML;
    }    

</script>

<div class="gap" ><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1','x');" id="x">Click here<div style="float:right;">[+]</div></a></div>

<div id="id1" style="display:none;">This is foo</div>


<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id2','y');" id="y"><div id="click1" style="float:left;">Click here1</div>[+]</a>

<div id="id2" style="display:none;">click here1
<div> <a href="#"  onclick="edit('id2','id3');">Edit</a></div>
<div> <a href="submit.php"  onclick="submit('id2','id3');">submit</a></div>
</div>




<div id="id3" style="display:none;">Edit
<div> <a href="#"  onclick="cancel('id2','id4')">cancel</a></div>
</div>


<div id="id4" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Now when I click any div it expands,but the probem is the browser is refreshing from the top.beacause of that I need to go down again and should see the content..

I want to stay it on the particular div when I click on any particular div..

Please help me..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be telling the browser to refresh the page:

```
window.location=window.location;
```

Why?  If you don't want the browser to refresh (and I'm not really seeing a need to do so here) then simply don't modify `window.location`.  Especially if you're trying to do all of this in client-side code since refreshing the page effectively resets the application context for client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [anchors](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html) to navigate your page to a certain location.

Though I would recommend you re-write your code and possibly use jQuery if you want to expand a div in an animated manner

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor in your link

```
<a href="#aid1" ...
<a href="#aid2" ...
```

then in you desired div add tag

```
<a name="aid1"></a>
```

Comment: I have added the anchor :-)

Comment: Yep, now maybe it's good to know, that when getting [`anchors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.anchors#Notes) collection, IE9+ are the only browsers which find this anchor from the snippet, all others need `name` attribute.

Comment: Thank you I will edit the response. But  for example chrome under linux will navigate even to a div with the id so there is no need to use even anchor tag.

Comment: Yes, browsers navigate fine with `id`, but I was talking about `anchors` collection, just in case someone wants to create a list of all anchors on a page...